# Having some trouble updating to Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I tried updating Ruby using the RVM command:

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-rc2
```

It downloaded successfully, and then ended compiling with this error:

```
Error running 'make', please read
/Users/Daniel/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-rc2/make.log There has been an error
while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Here are some of the errors I found in the log:

```
Failed to configure -test-/win32/dln. It will not be installed. Failed
to configure -test-/win32/fd_setsize. It will not be installed. Failed
to configure dl/win32. It will not be installed. Failed to configure
fiddle/win32. It will not be installed. Failed to configure gdbm. It
will not be installed. Failed to configure openssl. It will not be
installed. Failed to configure win32ole. It will not be installed.
```

Also,

```
In file included from stubs.c:16:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/tk.h:78:11: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
#       include <X11/Xlib.h>
                ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [stubs.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/tk/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

I thought it may have been an issue since I just updated to Mac OS 10.9. I tried to reinstall X11, but still had no success.

Comment: This is weird. If you are running OSX why would it include X11 stuff and run some win32 tests?! I use homebrew and rbenv and had no problems on 10.8. Could it be that Maverick have problems with rvm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run:

```
rvm get head      # new version of rvm with fixes for mavericks problems
rvm install 2.0.0 # install latest known patchlevel of 2.0.0
```

the `rc2` was a release candidate, it should not be used you should always use latest released patchlevel unless you explicitly know it breaks your application.

Comment: Or even, `rvm install 2.0` and don't worry about the bug-fix versions.

Comment: @Dogweather the next version is 2.1.0, if you need latest ruby then use `rvm install ruby`